# Is it legal to get species stats from Edge of The Empire if you only have Age of Rebellion?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion

I am not talking about getting pirated pdf, just getting stats only fan-created "cheat sheets"
For example somebody posts on the  FFG forum a chart for character creation.  All it has are stats, for races no description.  So would that be copyright violation?

Comment: I'm voting to close as off-topic because this is a question about the law, not really about RPGs.  While we might have opinions, the RPG.SE community are not experts in copyright law.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? You want to publish cheat sheets with NPC stat block or are you afraid the FBI will bust in your door if you used fan-created material?

Comment: @Tynam We have questions about publishing and rules for copyright and they are on topic. It's just in the current form the question is hard to understand

Comment: If  someone posts character stat charts on the FFG forums to aid in character creation, but they only have stats, nothing else.

Comment: For Jin: Charts on FFG  forum with official character STATS only.

Comment: It's still really unclear what you're asking. Your title is asking about the legality of if you can get stats from one book if you only have the other book: that's a non-starter because you don't _have_ the first book, and it's unclear if you're asking "is this illegal?" or "is this okay by the game rules?". Your question _body_ only confuses that further by referring to fan-created cheat sheets. Are you asking if you'd be violating copyright by using Edge of the Empire cheat sheets with your Age of Rebellion game? Are you asking if _they're_ violating copyright by providing those sheets?

Comment: Are we specifically talking about the "Alien Species" ("unofficial species menagerie") pdf that is posted in the FFG forums, and has been for like a year now? Because that was posted by a FFG employee (it's mostly playtesting info, some of which has changed in actual publications), and if it were a copyright violation, FFG could have removed it from their forums a long long time ago (or not let their employee post it in the first place). Though, while checking it just now, I notice the link is currently dead.

Comment: Is it legal to use the race stats ONLY.  Even if you didn't buy the ENTIRE book.

Answer (score 6):

The rule of thumb is: **If material someone copied means you can avoid paying for the book it comes from, it's a copyright violation.**

So if these cheat sheets mean you don't have to buy *Edge of the Empire*, no, the cheat sheets are violating copyright.

Comment: I'm not really sure for that rule of thumb. You know, no matter how little you get from a book, you always can avoid paying for it.

Comment: @Flamma It's based on the "economic impact" prong of Fair Use doctrine: basically, the courts care whether the copying reduces the economic value of the original. If these cheatsheets mean lots of people can use content from of the book without buying it, Fair Use doesn't apply and full copyright liability is due.